# Issues updating file content via Drive API v3

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Trying to update an existing file (here, fileId is this.healthProfile) works using a direct request.

Trying via the files.update (preferred method) returns a status code 200 (ok), but doesnt update the content or anything.

```
 commitHealthProfileData: function(data) {
      console.log('commiting new health data:');
      console.log(data);
      gapi.client.request({
        path: '/upload/drive/v3/files/' + this.healthProfile,
        method: 'PATCH',
        params: {
          uploadType: 'media'
        },
        body: data
      }).then(
        function(res){console.log('committed succesfully !'); console.log(res);},
        function(err){console.log(err);},
        this
      );
    // @TODO: kpoman // check why this below bugs as it is the common way of updating
    //   gapi.client.drive.files.update({
    //       'fileId':this.healthProfile,
    //       'uploadType':'media',
    //       'media': {
    //         mimeType:'application/json',
    //         body:data
    //       }
    //     }).then(
    //       function(res) {
    //         console.log('committed');
    //         console.log(res);
    //       },
    //       function(err) {
    //         console.log('err....');
    //         console.log(err);
    //       },
    //       this
    //     );
    // }
```

any tips ?

Comment: What kind of file are you updating, and what's in `data`?

Comment: In data you have a json string. The call works well with the PATCH command but not via the discovered API. Btw, is there a way to debug the final http verb/command built from a discovered method to debug the difference between raw calling ?